# healthAgent unhealthy-maintenance shown in htop output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tpu

[image]

This entry is on htop output for a tpu VM instance. Does unhealthy-maintenance indicate any problem with the tpu-vm?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your TPU is unhealthy. When it does not recover from a maintenance event, you can use a recovery script to detect the TPU state and re-create the TPU. One example of this script [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/retry/retry.sh). Make sure you update variables at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates:

The node is under maintenance/priority boost caused rescheduling and will resume running once rescheduled. Try to use checkpoints for the fast recovery from all the maintenance events and try to detect maintenance events regularly and handle them accordingly as per your needs. For more information please check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus).